# How do I merge a Pull Request when develop branch out of date?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I am trying to merge my develop branch to the master branch via a pull request. On the pull request page, I am getting the message "Branch is out of date. Merge
master into
**develop
**to remedy."

The problem is that no updates have been made to the master branch since develop branched off of it, other than maybe automated repository upgrades.

I attempted to merge master into develop, but received the same message, just with the branch names swapped.

I understand that to resolve the issue I need to merge master into develop first. However, if I open a PR to go from master to develop, I get the same message as before. There is no mechanism to allow me to merge in those changes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause of this is squashing commits from `feature-branch` -> `develop` and then again squashing between `develop` and `master`. This is fairly easy to fix locally using the git command line. You'll need to have git installed on your machine and then you can follow the following steps:

- Click `Clone` in the top right and copy the url given. [image]

- Clone the repo: `git clone [COPIED URL]`
- Make sure you're on master: `git checkout master`
- Create a new branch: `git checkout -b fix_merge_conflicts`
- Merge from develop: `git merge develop`
- Git will give you a list of files with conflicts, open these and fix the conflicts by removing appropriate lines.
- Add the fixed files: `git add myfile.txt folder/otherfile.py`
- Commit your changes: `git commit`
- If the message looks okay, exit the editor (normally `vi`, so use `:wq` to exit).
- Checkout master again: `git checkout master`
- Merge in changes from your branch: `git merge fix_merge_conflicts`
- Checkout develop: `git checkout develop`
- Merge in changes from your branch: `git merge fix_merge_conflicts`
- Push all changes back to your Code Repository: `git push`